# How can I use checkboxes in the Excel-App?

Tags: excel

I’ve a little problem and I wanted to ask you to help me out. I created a to-do list in Excel with interactive checkboxes.  When I click on a checkbox after completing a task, the word is automatically crossed out. Everything works fine on my computer, but unfortunately when I try to use it on my smartphone in the Excel app, it doesn't works. Instead, it says "This version of Excel does not support the execution or interaction of form controls."

thanks for your help.

I’d like to use the To-Do list on my Smartphone.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.